# why the completionHandler callback is called delay then the progress(it's 1.0) in AFNetworking upload multiple images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-3

I am using AFNetworking3.0 for upload some images in iOS, code is shown below, the *images* is an array of UIImage. 
I have two questions:

1. In the progress block I print Log A when the `uploadProgress.fractionCompleted` is equal to 1.0, in the head of `completionHandler` block I print log B, then I found the time of log A and B is differs greatly. Is there some thing wrong or its normal?
2. When I upload multiple images, for a better performance and less upload time, should I create multiple requests or the way like below, which is the right choice?

The code looks like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URL_IMAGE_SERVER parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {           
  for(UIImage *eachImage in images) {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(eachImage, 0.5);
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"upload_picture" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
  }
} error:nil];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
  uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
  progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
     // This is not called back on the main queue.
     // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   });
 }
  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     if (error) {
     } else {
     }
  }];
[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: I've tried to format you rcode a little better, but some of the parenthesis don't line up. Code samples need to be indented four spaces at the beginning, and you shouldn't use tabs here. Also, with numeric lists, have a space after the . so that it renders properly in the markdown (i.e. 1. The first rather than 1.The first)

Comment: @AlBlue thanks for your remind.

Comment: Hi.. were you able to solve this?

Comment: @AhmedZ.Yes, I solved it. the reason of the first question is, when the server handled my files, it needs time. second, I found the better choice is upload multiple files in one time , it costs the less time.